# Converting an image to type double

Tags: matlab, image-processing, casting, computer-vision

I am reading an image with the following command:

```
lefty = imread('sintra2.JPG');
```

and `imshow();` gives me a good resault. but If I try to use:

```
lefty = double(imread('sintra2.JPG'));
```

`imshow()` gives me a white image. I am working with a relatively big image [shared here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8pOvOPjXcLcUE44NzZUMWtQOHc). Is there a connection?

How do I convert to double if at all it is necessary? I was told it is better to work with double when working on image processing and computer vision in MATLAB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read the image, its type was `uint8` and thus `lefty` contained the   values from 0 to 255 (2<sup>8</sup> = 256). When you used [**`double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), it converted the class from `uint8` to `double` but the values remained same i.e 0-255.

You need [**`im2double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) here which not only converts the values to double precision but also rescales the values in the range 0-1 by dividing all the entries of the input by the maximum possible value of the input data type. So in your case, as the input data type is `uint8` whose maximum possible value is 255, therefore all the values will be divided by 255. Note that it is possible that the maximum value in your image data may not be 255 but since the maximum possible value of `uint8` is 255, so all the values will be divided by 255.

So the following is what you're looking for:

```
lefty = imread('sintra2.JPG');
imshow(lefty)
figure
imshow(im2double(lefty))
```

Comment: I would consider rewording this: *"but also rescales the values between 0 and 1"*.  People may have the misconception that if your image data does not span the entire dynamic range of the data type (for example, having a min and max of 32 and 128 for `uint8`), `im2double` will scale this image so that the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 1.  All `im2double` does is that it detects what type the image is and divides all entries in the input by the largest possible value of the input type.  There is no additional scaling performed other than the division.  That's just me and I like to nitpick.

Comment: @rayryeng It seemed obvious to me before but now after reading your comment and the other answer, I agree with what you said. So edited it as per your recommendation. Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the data type that `imshow` requires. If the image is of type `int`, its range should be between 0 and 255. If it is double – between 0.0 and 1.0. Try this:

```
lefty = imread('sintra2.JPG');
imshow(lefty)
```

or:

```
lefty = imread('sintra2.JPG');
imshow(double(lefty)/double(max(lefty(:))))
```

Comment: So basically the image is fine and converted to double and the only problem is the `imshow()` representation?

Comment: @havakok To avoid problems like this in the future, let `imshow` scale the image for you: `imshow(lefty, []);`  The second argument specifies what the minimum and maximum intensity map to and by doing `[]` it scales your image data such that the smallest intensity is 0 and the largest intensity is 1 for a `double` type image.